# Как запускать bash-файл вне директории с pom-файлом?

Tags: bash, cmd, консоль, cucumber

Я запускаю run.sh файл, содержащий в себе

```java
mvn clean test -Dcucumber.options="/Users/autotests/src/test/resources/features --tags @TEST21"
```

но терминал кидает ошибку про то, что этот файл доложен быть в той же директории, что и pom

```
The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/Users/Documents/work info). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
```

Возможно ли всё-таки как-то обойти эту ошибку, не помещая bash-файл в директорию с pom. Есть ли какой-то способ прописать путь к pom-файлу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Удалось найти решение:

```
mvn -f /path/to/pom/pom.xml clean test -Dcucumber.options="..."
```